# Separating template friend function's declaration and definition

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I write a class template

```cpp
template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
class FixedMatrix {
    /* ... */
    template<std::size_t P>
    friend auto dot (const FixedMatrix<T, N, M> &matrix1, const FixedMatrix<T, M, P> &matrix2) -> FixedMatrix<T, N, P>;
};
```

in `FixedMatrix.h` and write the definition of `dot`

```cpp
template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M, std::size_t P>
auto dot(const FixedMatrix<T, N, M> &matrix1, const FixedMatrix<T, M, P> &matrix2) -> FixedMatrix<T, N, P> {
    /* ... */
}
template class FixedMatrix<std::complex<double>, 2, 2>;
```

in `FixedMatrix.cpp`.

Reading https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-friends, I add

```cpp
template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
class FixedMatrix;

template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M, std::size_t P>
auto dot(const FixedMatrix<T, N, M> &matrix1, const FixedMatrix<T, M, P> &matrix2) -> FixedMatrix<T, N, P>;
```

above the definition of class `FixedMatrix`. However, the compiler still cannot find reference to `dot()`. If I modify the declaration of the friend function as

```cpp
template<std::size_t P>
friend auto dot <> (const FixedMatrix<T, N, M> &matrix1, const FixedMatrix<T, M, P> &matrix2) -> FixedMatrix<T, N, P>;
```

the compiler will complain that "function template partial specialization is not allowed" and "invalid use of template-id 'dot<>' in declaration of primary template".

Is there any way to separate template friend function's declaration and definition?

Comment: You shouldn't define a template function (`dot` in your case) in a .cpp file, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file. Also, since `dot` is a free function template, it probably needs to be templated over `N` and `M` as well

Comment: well but as I explicitly instantiate the template instance I need at the end of `FixedMatrix.cpp` as `template class FixedMatrix<std::complex<double>, 2, 2>;` it should work I think

Comment: But `dot` is a template also: It must be made available in a header file so that you can (implicitly or explicitly) instantiate it somewhere.

Comment: Slightly unrelated, I try to avoid template friends if I can. A strategy is to define a non-template friend struct with static templated methods. https://godbolt.org/z/jWGTdfWKs

Comment: How to instantiate this? I tried for example
`template auto dot(const FixedMatrix<std::complex<double>, 2, 2> &matrix1,
                  const FixedMatrix<std::complex<double>, 2, 2> &matrix2) -> FixedMatrix<std::complex<double>, 2, 2>;`
but does not seem to work

Comment: Can you explain why you need to explicitly instantiate these templates? This is seldomly necessary, since the templates are implicitly instantiated when you use them.

Comment: Because if I do not explicitly instantiate them, then the compiler just cannot find references to them if I separate template declarations and definitions

Comment: Then why is it so important to you, that you seperate the declaration and definition of your templates? In principle you can do that (see the SO question and answer I wrote in my first comment) but that will always limit you to just the few explicit template instantiations you provide in the cpp file that contains the definitions.

Comment: Not for a compelling reason but because I'm adding this to an existing code that separates template declarations and definitions and trying to make a consistent coding style without refactoring a lot.

Comment: I would argue that you need a compelling reason not to define your templates in a header file. I have the feeling you are making your life harder than it needs to be. I think the best seperation you can achieve without obscurity is by having the declarations in a header file and the definition in an `.inl` file which you include at the end of your header https://godbolt.org/z/aqnrnMb74